# Selenium - FirefoxDriver not accepting arguments in code

Tags: selenium, geckodriver

I am unable to use arguments for new FirefoxDriver as per code:

```
        File pathBinary = new File("C:\\Users\\myname\\AppData\\Local\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe");
        FirefoxBinary firefoxBinary = new FirefoxBinary(pathBinary);
        FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile(); 
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxBinary,firefoxProfile);
        //WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

I get an error saying "remove arguments to match FirefoxProfile();

When I try using just new FirefoxDriver() I get:

```
        org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Cannot find firefox binary in PATH. Make sure firefox is installed. OS appears to be: WIN8_1
```

I am using:

```
        geckodriver-v0.19.1-win32
        selenium-server-standalone-3.7.1
```

Any help most appreciated.

Comment: Which configuration are you exactly trying? `FirefoxProfile` and/or `FirefoxBinary`?

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass them in as Firefox options try the following

```
FirefoxProfile ffprofile = new FirefoxProfile();
FirefoxBinary ffBinary = new FirefoxBinary(new File("path to your firefox 
executable"));
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.setProfile(ffprofile);
options.setProfile(ffBinary);
options.setCapability(FirefoxOptions.FIREFOX_OPTIONS,options);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
```

Comment: options.setBinary(ffBinary);